# Razor Pages with JQuery & DRY principle

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm writing a web app with ASP.NET Core, Entity Framework Core and Razor Pages.
I have many pages that use jQuery to speak to the page controller: dropdown value from one selection may change another dropdown like this:

```js
$(function () {
    $("#Position_PositionState").on("change", function () {
        var projectId = $("#Position_ProjectId").val();
        $.getJSON(`?handler=Project&projectId=${projectId}`, function (response) {
            if (response === "Inactive") {
                var state = document.getElementById('Position_PositionState');
                for (var i = 0; i < state.options.length; i++) {
                    if (state.options[i].text === response) {
                        state.selectedIndex = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The code on the page that gives JSON responses looks like this:

```cs
public async Task<JsonResult> OnGetProjectAsync(string projectId)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(projectId))
    {
        if (Int32.TryParse(projectId, out int id))
        {
            var project = await _context.Projects.FindAsync(id);
            if (project != null)
            {
                if (project.ProjectState == ProjectState.Active)
                    return new JsonResult("Active");
                else
                    return new JsonResult("Inactive");
            }
            else return new JsonResult("Inactive");
        }
        else
        {
            return new JsonResult("Inactive");
        }
    }
    return new JsonResult("Inactive");
}
```

The questions are:

- How to move the code repeated on many pages (Controller code) to a separate utility
  class and pass ApplicationContext to it.
- How and where to instantiate that utility class.
- How to call that utility class from jQuery.

I can only use this code on .cshtml.cs page that has the .cshtml view with jQuery, not in other places.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. You say "dropdown value from one selection may change another dropdown". But the Javascript code only shows one dropdown (apparently) `#Position_PositionState` that might change itself, not another dropdown. Maybe if you show us the Razor too, it would be more clear? Also in what way do you need the same code to be called. If it is the same code, why not call the same `Action` from different pages? If it is not exactly the same code, what does change and needs to be parametrized?

Comment: Hi @VollerSterne, you cannot call utility class from jquery, what you should do is to call utility class in your PageModel/Controller code. Then using ajax calls the PageModel/Controller.

Comment: If you have an Action that's used on multiple controllers, then create a "base controller" and inherit your multiple controllers from that.  Put your action in the base controller and it will be available on all razor pages for controllers that inherit from base controller.

Comment: @Laurent Gabiot that particular ajax prevents dropdown to change to Active if the project is inactive.

Comment: @Rena thanks I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer, but your `Action` code could be simplified, there are too many `return`s and `if`s.

An example:

```cs
public async Task<JsonResult> OnGetProjectAsync(string projectId)
{
    if (!int.TryParse(projectId, out int id))
    {
        return new JsonResult("Inactive");
    }
    var project = await _context.Projects.FindAsync(id);
    var result = project?.ProjectState == ProjectState.Active 
        ? "Active"
        : "Inactive";
    return new JsonResult(result);
}
```

Checking `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` is not needed because `int.TryParse` will return `false` is the `ProjectId` string is null or whitespace.

There is also no need to explicitly check if `project` is null because wa can propagate the null with the `?` operator, and `null == ProjectState.Active` will always be false.

Comment: *Not the answer* - this isn't [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) - non-answers should be in comments (though clearly a little too much for comment) or as an extra to a real answer.